# cannot use graph.data() in neo4j v3

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo

I am trying to run the code:

```
from py2neo import Graph
graph = Graph(config['DATABASE']['ENDPOINT'])
graph.data("MATCH (u:Users) return u.id, u.email LIMIT 4")
```

however I get the error message:

```
AttributeError: 'Graph' object has no attribute 'data'
```

This is exactly the same format given on the py2neo website

```
from py2neo import Graph
graph = Graph(password="excalibur")
graph.data("MATCH (a:Person) RETURN a.name, a.born LIMIT 4")
[{'a.born': 1964, 'a.name': 'Keanu Reeves'},
 {'a.born': 1967, 'a.name': 'Carrie-Anne Moss'},
 {'a.born': 1961, 'a.name': 'Laurence Fishburne'},
 {'a.born': 1960, 'a.name': 'Hugo Weaving'}]
```

any ideas on the error message?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you are not on the version 3 of py2neo, try to upgrade :

```
pip install py2neo --upgrade
```

This simple script works fine :

```
from py2neo import Graph
graph = Graph(host="localhost")
d = graph.data("MATCH (t:TwitterAccount) RETURN t.user_screen_name LIMIT 4")

print(d)
```

-

```
ikwattro@graphaware ~/dev> python test.py
[{u't.user_screen_name': u'meichsnerbros'}, {u't.user_screen_name': u'renato_umeton'}, {u't.user_screen_name': u'kdnuggets'}, {u't.user_screen_name': u'sabrinaDijkhuiz'}]
ikwattro@graphaware ~/dev>
```

Comment: i am on the latest version of py2neo - still not working

Answer (score 2):

In the latest version of py2neo (Version: 4.3.0), this works:

```
graph.run("MATCH (n:Document) RETURN n.title LIMIT 5").data()
```

more information can be found here: https://py2neo.org/v4/database.html#the-graph

Answer (score 1):

`Graph.data` was added in 3.1.1. If you don't have that, it won't be available.